# Can we run powershell.exe on a remote windows machine from mac?

Tags: java, powershell, processbuilder, invoke-command

I have a piece of Java code in which I am using Java Processbuilder to run powershell command on a remote machine. The remote machine is Windows but can I run this from Mac? I don't have Mac so I can't test it but users might have.

String[] commands = new String[] {"powershell.exe", "invoke-command", "-computerName", "myCom"};
new ProcessBuilder(commands);

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't make sense. You cannot use ProcessBuilder to run _remote_ commands. Executing this on a Mac would try to atart Powershell on the Mac.

Comment: Thank you. It works with Windows but as you said won't work with Mac. I have to write a different piece of code for Mac now :( .

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. I was thinking I can invoke the powershell somehow to run on the remote machine rather than the client itself. But I didn't find a way to do so . So had to use that code for Windows and write a separate one for Linux.